Holding the state of a ControlValueAccessor component using signals requires "{ allowSignalWrites: true }"
I have this component implementing ControlValueAccessor and holding the internal state in a signal value:
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    
    // internal state
    value = signal('');

    // implement writeValue()
    writeValue(value: string): void { this.value.set(value); } // <-- writeValue is updating the signal
    
    // other methods
    
}

The InputComponent is used in a template like this:
    <!-- ClientComponent template -->
    <app-input [formControl]="fcUrl"/>

where fcUrl is a FormControl:
export class ClientComponent {

    url = input.required<string>();
    fcUrl = new FormControl<string>('');

    constructor() {

        effect(() => {

            // update the FormControl when new value for 'url' arrives:
            this.fcUrl.setValue(this.url());

        }, { allowSignalWrites: true });

    }

}

Here, { allowSignalWrites: true } is necessary because the writeValue() of InputComponent is setting the value of a signal. Otherwise a runtime error is thrown :
NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a `computed` or an `effect` by default. Use `allowSignalWrites` in the `CreateEffectOptions` to enable this inside effects.

What's the right way of updating the FormControl using an effect() without using the allowSignalWrites flag in this scenario (other than replacing the effect() with rxjs, e.g. toObservable(this.url).pipe(...)) ?

You can use untracked which according to the documentation will:

Execute an arbitrary function in a non-reactive (non-tracking) context. The executed function can, optionally, return a value.

This is a better alternative to "{ allowSignalWrites: true }" which will not trigger. Since the changes are untracked the effect does not trigger the error
"ERROR RuntimeError: NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a computed or an effect by default. Use allowSignalWrites in the CreateEffectOptions to enable this inside effects."
...
export class Child {
  signUpForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
  });
  url = input.required<string>();

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      // update the FormControl when new value for 'url' arrives:
      const url = this.url();
      untracked(() => this.signUpForm.patchValue({ name: url }));
    });
  }
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  effect,
  input,
  signal,
  untracked,
  WritableSignal,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  FormControl,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  NgControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule, NgClass } from '@angular/common';

type InputProps = {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  type: 'text' | 'password' | 'number';
  value: string;
  label: string;
  formControlName: string;
  placeholder: string;
  checkValidation: boolean;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgClass],
  template: `
  <input
      [type]="type()"
      #val
      (focus)="markAsTouched()"
      (input)="valueChanged(val.value)"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      [value]="_value()"
    />
    <label [for]="label()">
      {{ label() }}
    </label>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: InputComponent,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  public readonly label = input.required<InputProps['label']>();
  public readonly checkValidation = input<InputProps['checkValidation']>(false);
  public readonly placeholder = input<InputProps['placeholder']>();

  public type = input<InputProps['type']>('text');
  onChange = (value: any) => {};
  _value: WritableSignal<any> = signal(null);
  onTouched = () => {};

  touched = false;

  disabled = false;

  writeValue(value: number) {
    this._value.set(value);
  }

  valueChanged(val: string) {
    this.onChange(val);
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, InputComponent, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
      <app-input 
        label="Name"
        formControlName="name" 
      ></app-input>
    </form>

    {{signUpForm.value | json}}
  `,
})
    export class Child {
      signUpForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(''),
      });
      url = input.required<string>();

      constructor() {
        effect(() => {
          // update the FormControl when new value for 'url' arrives:
          const url = this.url();
          untracked(() => this.signUpForm.patchValue({ name: url }));
        });
      }
    }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
  <app-child [url]="url"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  url = Math.random().toString();

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.url = Math.random().toString();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

You can use the Angular RXJS bridging functions https://angular.dev/ecosystem/rxjs-interop.
url = input.required<string>();
fcUrl = new FormControl<string>('');

constructor() {
    toObservable(this.url)
        .pipe(
            takeUntilDestroyed()
        )
        .subscribe(value =>
            this.fcUrl.setValue(value))
}

This will effectively convert the Signal into an RXJS Observable that will trigger on each value change of the signal starting with the initial value.
Use the takeUntilDestroyed() function from @angular/core/rxjs-interop to terminate the Observable upon destruction of your component.
